# How to filter a data table for rows with the latest timestamp in R

Tags: sql, r, filter, timestamp

I have a datatable of 48 rows, extracted from database via a SQL query.

I want to filter for the latest timestamp within this dataset.

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Many thanks!

table is attached for clarity:
[image]

Comment: I realise there are distinct features of the rows i am trying to pull in the USER_NAME being 'SYS' but this will not be a constant and so i cannot filter based on this. The only applicable filter would be the latest timestamp

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data and all necessary code. Even if we had your code, we wouldn't be able to run it on a picture of data. You've also tagged 2 languages, so it's unclear how you're trying to do this

Comment: Also, searching SO for ["[r] is:question filter max value"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+is%3Aquestion+filter+max+value) yields almost 400 posts. At least one or two of those should cover it—what research have you done that didn't help?

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you would do something like:

```
select t.*
from <your logic here>
order by timestamp desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support `fetch first`.  It might be spelled `limit` or `select top` in your database.

Answer (score 0):

In R, assuming your data is stored in a dataframe called `df` and :

```
tail(df[order(df$TIMESTAMP), ])[1,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your suggestions!

I have found an answer using dplyr:

filter(my_table, timestamp_col == max(timestamp_col)

So for example with the inbuilt mtcars dataset, to find all the cars with the largest number of gears, use
filter(mtcars, gear == max(gear))

In base R, the same thing would be mtcars[mtcars$gear == max(mtcars$gear),]